# How to append a list in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm reading a dataframe and trying to insert a list inside another list and then converting it to json file. I'm using python 3 and 0.25.3 version of pandas for it.

============================

**Data that I'm reading:**

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer    part_number   number_client

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          7897           982

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          888            12

92    Hong Kong      CUST-88888         China           147            288
```

============================

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd 
import json

data = pd.read_excel(path)

data["part_number"] = data["part_number"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
data["number_client"]  = data["number_client"].apply(lambda x: str(x))

data = data.groupby(["id", "label", "id_customer", "label_customer"], as_index=False).agg("#".join)

data["part_number"] = data["part_number"].apply(lambda x: {"part": x})
data["number_client"] = data["number_client"].apply(lambda x: {"client": x})

data["id_customer"] = data["id_customer"].apply(lambda x: {"id": x})
data["label_customer"] = data["label_customer"].apply(lambda x: {"label": x})

data["Customer"] = data.apply(lambda x: [{**x["id_customer"], **x["label_customer"]}],axis=1)
data["number"] = data.apply(lambda x: [{**x["part_number"], **x["number_client"]}], axis=1)

data = data[["id", "label", "Customer","number"]]

data.to_json(path)
```

=============================

**What is expected:**

```
[{
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Sao Paulo",
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "CUS-99992",
        "label": "Brazil",
        "number": [{
        "part": "7897",
        "client": "892"
    },
    {
       "part": "888",
       "client": "12"
    }]
    }]  
}, 
{
    "id": 92,
    "label": "Hong Kong",
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "CUS-88888",
        "label": "China",
        "number": [{
        "part": "147",
        "client": "288"
    }]
    }] 
}]
```

============================

**What I'm getting:**

```
[{
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Sao Paulo",
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "CUS-99992",
        "label": "Brazil"
    }],
    "number": [{
        "part": "7897",
        "client": "892"
    }],
    "number": [{
        "part": "888",
        "client": "12"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 92,
    "label": "Hong Kong",
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "CUS-88888",
        "label": "China"
    }],
    "number": [{
        "part": "147",
        "client": "288"
    }]
}]
```

======================

I tried to do the same thing using `iterrows` function (and posted a question here 'Dataframe and conversion to JSON using Pandas'), but some people recommend me to try another way using another function. I know that is a stupid thing add `number` object inside my `data`, but I already tried of others way.

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you give an sample input dataframe?

Comment: Hi, could you show what the dataframe `data` looks like at the end of the processing?

Comment: I edited my question @ScottBoston!! tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the following reformatting function:

```
def reformat(row):
    d1 = { 'part': str(row.part_number), 'client': str(row.number_client)}
    d2 = { 'id': row.id_customer, 'label': row.label_customer, 'number': [d1] }
    return { 'id': row.id, 'label': row.label, 'Customer': [d2] }
```

Then apply it the following way:

```
df.apply(reformat, axis=1).to_json('result.json', orient='records')
```

The result (reformatted for readability) is:

```
[ { "id":6,
    "label":"Sao Paulo",
    "Customer":[
      { "id":"CUST-99992",
        "label":"Brazil",
        "number":[{"part":"7897","client":"982"}]
      }
    ]
  },
  { "id":92,
    "label":"Hong Kong",
    "Customer":[
      { "id":"CUST-88888",
        "label":"China",
        "number":[{"part":"147","client":"288"}]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

## Edit following the comment

To cope with the variant of **multiple** rows for a **single** *label* /
*label_customer*, take another approach:

Start from defining the following functions:

1. Get the content of *number* attribute:

   ```
   def getNum(grp):
       return eval(grp[['part', 'client']].to_json(orient='records'))
   ```

   Note *eval* in this function. Otherwise the result would be a string
   (instead of list of dictionaries).
2. Get the content of *Customer* attribute:

   ```
   def getCust(grp):
       r0 = grp.iloc[0]
       return { 'id': r0.id_customer, 'label': r0.label_customer, 'number': getNum(grp) }
   ```
3. Get the content of the whole JSON element for the current group:

   ```
   def getGrp(grp):
       r0 = grp.iloc[0]
       return { 'id': r0.id, 'label': r0.label, 'Customer': getCust(grp) }
   ```

Then convert column types to *string*:

```
df.part_number = df.part_number.astype('str')
df.number_client = df.number_client.astype('str')
```

And to get the final result, run:

```
df.rename(columns={'part_number': 'part', 'number_client': 'client'})\
    .groupby(['id', 'label', 'id_customer', 'label_customer'])\
    .apply(getGrp).to_json(orient='values')
```

The above code:

- Renames *part_number* and *number_client* to *part* and *client*,
  respectively. This change is needed to generate proper element
  names by *getNum*.
- Groups the DataFrame (as in your code).
- Applies *getGrp* function to each group. The result is a *Series* of
  JSON elements.
- And finally *to_json* converts this *Series* to a list of JSON elements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Valdi_Bo, but didn't solved my problem. I edited my question now.. hope this helps.. for example: if all my contents inside my cells in row 0 are the same  in row 2 (except in `part_number` and `number_client`) a new object with `id`,`label`, `id_customer` and `label_customer`  wont be created.. just a new `number` list will be added, like showed in my question description..

Comment: I changed my solution to cope with the case of more rows for a single *label* / *label_customer*.